# splitting out my data frame and automating my plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I aim to automate my plot so that i see sequently present my data in my dataFrame.
I have a data frame that holds data for many years 
Is there away to subsequently (automatically) plot portions of my date frame.
like plot first three months then after 10 seconds the following three ?

```
In [11]: import pandas_datareader.data as web

In [12]: from datetime import datetime

In [13]: start = datetime(2015, 2, 9)

In [14]: end = datetime(2017, 5, 24)

In [15]: f = web.DataReader('F', 'morningstar', start, end)

In [16]: f.head()
Out[16]: 



    Symbol Date   Close High Low Open Volume

    F 2015-02-09 15.92 16.03 15.72 15.76 20286720
    2015-02-10 16.09 16.14 15.91 16.05 27928530
    2015-02-11 16.25 16.31 16.01 16.08 34285331
    2015-02-12 16.36 16.45 16.30 16.34 23738806
    2015-02-13 16.30 16.36 16.19 16.33 19954568


  f[["Open","Close","High"]].plot(title="DF")
```

Comment: You can make animations using matplotlib (doc: https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html). I also like this tutorial https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/. Why don't you read up on how to use these functions, create simple animations, then animations that use your DataFrame, and ask a more specific question if you encounter a specific problem.